# Create a widget without tab index

Tags: python, tkinter

Im creating a form with python3 and tkinter, with a fwe buttons and a scrollbar. When I navigate the form via tab and ctrl-tab, it focus all the buttons AND the scrollbar too. I would like to exclude the scrollbar (and possibly other widgets) from the tabstop index. Is that possible?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `takefocus` attribute of the scrollbar and other widgets to `False`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ill try. Regards

Comment: It works like a charm! myScrollbar.config(takefocus=False) Thank you again Bryan